# Consume OAuth Tokens in ASP.Net Web Api 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, owin

I have created a brand new WebService using ASP.Net Web Api 2.0 and am trying to use authorization based on an OAuth JWT token.  I have all of the basic wiring done with OWIN, but when I use the [Authorize] attribute, it fails, even for a valid token.  Can you help.

**Edit: I narrowed down the issue.  It seems that the key is RS256 and SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider doesn't handle that... Either that or I am passing the Key Provider the wrong information.  Any ideas how to fix that?**

Here is the code of my startup.cs

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace SecuredApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            var config = ConfigureWebApi();

            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Bearer"));
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            return config;
        }

        private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Issuer");
            var audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Audience");
            var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Secret");

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            var jwtBearerAuthenticationOptions = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = new IIssuerSecurityKeyProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider(issuer, secret)
                }
            };
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                jwtBearerAuthenticationOptions);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it fails` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  If I put an Authorize attribute, it fails as "UnAuthorized"... if I don't the User on the context has no claims...